# Cannot connect to remote docker host via SSH forwarded domain socket

Tags: docker, docker-compose, freebsd

I want to be able to user `docker-compose` with a remote daemon. I created a local forward to the remote daemon socket like so:

```
#!/bin/sh

export SOCKET_DIR=$HOME/.remote-sockets
mkdir -p $SOCKET_DIR
echo "Creating SSH Dokcer Socket Tunnel"
socat "UNIX-LISTEN:/$SOCKET_DIR/docker.sock,reuseaddr,fork" \
EXEC:'ssh freebsd@107.170.216.79 socat STDIO UNIX-CONNECT\:/var/run/docker.sock'
```

With that script running, I export the following environment variables:

```
DOCKER_API_VERSION 1.19
COMPOSE_API_VERSION 1.19
DOCKER_HOST unix://$HOME/.remote-sockets/docker.sock
```

With those variables set, I can verify running `docker ps` shows me the remote containers and not my local daemon's containers. Furthermore, `docker-compose ps` also seems to connect to the remote daemon, as it returns an empty list. If I shut down the SSH tunnel, it fails saying it can't connect to the docker daemon.

The trouble is when I try to run `docker-compose up`. I've also tried `docker-compose -H unix://$HOME/.remote-sockets/docker.sock up`. Both commands give me the following:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon - you might need to run `docker-machine start default`.
```

Local Versions:

```
Docker version 1.11.0, build 4dc5990
docker-compose version 1.8.0, build 94f7016
(Gentoo Linux)
```

Remote Versions:

```
Docker version 1.7.0-dev, build 582db78
(FreeBSD 11.0-RELEASE-p1)
```

Why won't `docker-compose up` work with a different socket when the other commands seem to communicate with it fine?

Comment: Does the same setup work trying to control a Linux host running Docker 1.11? Controlling a Linux host running Docker 1.7.x?  That FreeBSD port of docker is the greatest unknown there as it's old and never really got past "experimental".